# Differentiate $ \log y=e^{x}+4$ and $\frac{1}{2^{y}}=\frac{1}{2^{x}}+5$

Tags: calculus

Differentiate

> $$ (1) \log y=e^{x}+4$$ $$(2) \frac{1}{2^{y}}=\frac{1}{2^{x}}+5$$

Please write full steps and if possible give an explantion.
Thank You.

Comment: [How to ask a homework question?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1803/how-to-ask-a-homework-question)

Comment: @user32251: Please see http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1803/how-to-ask-a-homework-question

Comment: You already have a hint below. You should at least try to solve it yourself.

Comment: It seems an oddly worded question. One doesn't really differentiate an *equation*, one differentiates a *function*. I would have expected something like "If $\log y=e^x+4$, find $\frac{dy}{dx}$."

Comment: Editing many times by different users has changed the question! I can't figure out what was wrong with the first version.

Comment: This is the original question.Someone edited it wrongly.

Comment: You should probably change the title as well

Comment: No thank you.  Do your own homework.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$(1)$

There are two ways to solve the first one. If you are familiar with implicit differentiation then differentiate both sides to get
$$\begin{align*}
\frac{d}{dx}(\log y)&=\frac{d}{dx}(e^x+4)\\
\frac{1}{y}\frac{dy}{dx}&=e^x+0\\
\frac{dy}{dx}&=ye^x\end{align*}$$
If you are not familiar with implicit differentiation then write $\log y=e^x+4$ as
$$y=e^{e^x+4}$$
Differentiate and get
$$\begin{align*}
&\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{d}{dx}\left(e^{e^x+4}\right)\\
&\frac{dy}{dx}=e^x\cdot e^{e^x+4}=ye^x\end{align*}$$

---

(2)

In the second question we can also use implicit differentiation or explicitly solve for y. Using implicit we get
$$\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{2^y}&=\frac{1}{2^x}+5\\
\frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{1}{2^y}\right)&=\frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{1}{2^x}+5\right)\\
\frac{-\ln2}{2^y}\frac{dy}{dx}&=\frac{-\ln2}{2^x}\\
\frac{dy}{dx}&=\frac{2^y}{2^x}\\
\end{align*}$$
But since $2^y=\frac{1}{\frac{1}{2^x}+5}$
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{\frac{1}{\frac{1}{2^x}+5}}{2^x}=\frac{1}{1+5\cdot2^x}$$
The other approach is by explicitly solving for $y$ and then differentiating as follows:
$$\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{2^y}&=\frac{1}{2^x}+5\\
\Longrightarrow2^y&=\frac{1}{\frac{1}{2^x}+5}\\
\Longrightarrow\log_2(2^y)&=\log_2\left(\frac{1}{\frac{1}{2^x}+5}\right)\\
\Longrightarrow y&=\log_2 1-\log_2(\frac{1}{2^x}+5)\\
\Longrightarrow y&=-\frac{\ln(\frac{1}{2^x}+5)}{\ln2}\\
\frac{dy}{dx}&=\frac{-1}{\ln2}\frac{d}{dx}\left(\ln\left(\frac{1}{2^x}+5\right)\right)\\
\frac{dy}{dx}&=\frac{-1}{\ln2}\cdot\frac{1}{\frac{1}{2^x}+5}\cdot \frac{-\ln2}{2^x}\\
\frac{dy}{dx}&=\frac{1}{1+5\cdot2^x}
\end{align*}$$

*Remember that $\displaystyle\log_b a= \frac{\log_c a}{\log_c b}$

Comment: You Saw wrong second question.

Comment: @Neer I fixed it now

Comment: @Neer This is a rather poor comment to someone who wrote you a very long and detailed answer to your badly-written question.

Comment: Sorry and thank you @E.O.

Answer (score 0):

For the first one, you need to exponentiation both sides of the equation to get
$y = e^{(4+e^x)}$ (assuming you are finding $dy/dx$), then go to the following for an exact step-by-step solution:
[Wolfram|Alpha1](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=derivative%20of%20e%5E%28e%5E%28x%29%2b4%29)

For the second one, the first step is to re-arrange it as:
$$\frac{1}{ 5+\frac{1}{2^x}} = 2^y$$
Then take the base to logarithm of each side to get:

$$y = \log_2 \frac{1}{ 5+\frac{1}{2^x}}$$

then to compute the derivative go to the following:

[Wolfram|Alpha2](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=derivative%20of%20log%20base%202%20of%20%281/%20%5B5%2b%281/%282%5Ex%29%5D%29)

<sup>Wolfram Alpha is a great tool for little pesky problems like this.... but don't overdo it!</sup>

Comment: If you use the hyperlink tool above the edit box, it usually takes care of the escaping correctly so that your link does what it should.

Answer (score 0):

$$\log y= e^{x} +4$$
$$ e^{\log y}= e^{(e^{x}+4)}$$
$$\Rightarrow y= e^{(e^{x}+4)}$$
Now differntiate with respect to $x$, we get,
$$ \frac{dy}{dx}= e^{(e^{x}+4)}.e^{x}$$

$$\frac{1}{2^{y}}=\frac{1}{2^{x}+5}$$
$$ \therefore 2^{y}= 2^{x}+5$$
$$ \log{2^{y}}=\log{(2^{x}+5)}$$
$$\Rightarrow y\log 2= \log{(2^{x}+5)}$$
Now differentiate with respect to $x$, we get,
$$\log 2\frac{dy}{dx}= \frac{1}{2^{x}+5}.2^{x}\log 2$$
$$\therefore \frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{2^{x}}{2^{x}+5}$$

Comment: Second question has changed.